# How to show success alert if transaction success in web sql?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var brand = "Blare";
var price = "2000$";
var color = "black";
var success = tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO car (brand, price, color) VALUES ('"+brand+"','"+price+"','"+color+"' ")");

if(success) {
    alert("successfully added");
}
```

How to show success alert if transaction success in web sql?

Comment: your sql injection

Comment: You have extra double quotes in the last _color+"' ")");_ change this to _color+"' )");_

Answer (score 0):

Really simple ways. Check this link [github](https://gist.github.com/andyj/1599544)

```
db.transaction(
    function(tx){
        tx.executeSql( "INSERT INTO car(rules) VALUES(?)",
        ['You do not talk about Fight Club'],
        onSuccessExecuteSql)
    }
)

function onSuccessExecuteSql( tx, results ){
    console.log( 'Execute SQL completed' )
}
```